# Preprocessor check for Xcode 4.4 or newer

Tags: xcode, xcode4, clang, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to test (with the preprocessor) if a file is being compiled under Xcode 4.4 or newer?  Or, more particularly, to test if the compiler will automatically `@synthesize` properties and throw a compile error if not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this to test for the feature:

```
#if (defined(__clang__) && __has_feature(objc_default_synthesize_properties))
#warning Got it
#else
#error omg no auto synthesis
#endif
```

the full list of features is documented here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html

Comment: Yeah, it's cleaner to check for the feature rather than the compiler version as I was doing.

Comment: @BradLarson but your answer answered one of the two parts of the question +1.

Answer (score 2):

Because this was made available with the 4.x versions of the LLVM compiler, you should be able to use the following to test for the presence of a new enough version:

```
#if __clang__ && (__clang_major__ >= 4)
 // New version code here
#else
 // Fallback code for older version here
#endif
```